# How to remove the RatingBar star border stroke in Android?

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am using `RatingBar` in my application. For this rating bar app star I am getting the border stroke. How can I remove this border stroke? Below are my xml and screenshot of the bar.

```
    <RatingBar
          android:id="@+id/rating"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
          android:numStars="5"           
          android:stepSize="0.8"
          android:scaleX="0.8"
          android:scaleY="0.8"
          android:isIndicator="true"
          android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/userName" />
```

[image]

Comment: you have to use your own custom drawables

Answer (score 0):

you need custom your ratingbar and provide your own images,default ratingbar's image contain  border stroke:

```
<style name="RatingBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_selector</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">34dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">34dp</item>
</style>


<item android:id="@+android:id/background" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/emotion_composer_rating_small_icon" />

<item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/emotion_composer_rating_small_icon" />

<item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/emotion_composer_rating_small_icon_highlighted" />
```